# Restarting windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a windows application C#4.0 with multithreadings problem is when i close the application ,the process stays on, no matter what i do so i have to do this:

```
environment.exit(1);
```

or the process wouldnt close,

problem is if i executed environment.exit(1) then application.restart() wouldn't work then.

any idea how to kill the process and then restart ?

Comment: Kill all the threads your program has spawned?

Comment: Shouldn't you try to fix your multithreading problem first?

Answer (score 4):

Use the debugger.  After you closed your main window, use Debug + Break All.  Debug + Windows + Threads.  Look at the call stack of the threads you see listed there to find the one that is preventing the program from terminating.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to make all your worker threads run in the background (set `IsBackground` to true before starting them). Background threads don't prevent the process from exiting.

Comment: i did that and it still prevent the process from exiting not to mention i do abort all the threads on the closing event!

Answer (score 0):

threads that your application creates must be terminated before exiting the application otherwise CPU and/or memory will be consumed by the hanging threads

Comment: there are some threads which have to run all the time they are listening to a port and gettig data from it , anyw ay i abort all threads on the closing event but still the process doesnt end.

Answer (score 0):

You can Exit application completely by typing this:

```
Application.Exit();
```

For Restarting Application Completely:

```
Application.Restart();
```